# How to make a certain window pop up if a certain number is put in

Tags: java, calculator

I was wondering how do i make a certain window pop up if I input a certain number for my java program.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Calculator_Menu
{
public static void main (String args [])
{
String MainMenu = " Calculator Options \n\n1. Addition\n2" +
" Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Exit";

    menu (MainMenu);
}

public static String menu (String info)
{
    String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (info);
    return choice;
}

public static int Addition ()
{
```

Comment: If you want one window to pop up if a certain number or numbers are entered, an `if` statement will work for that. If you want the content of the window to differ depending on what was entered, you may want to use a `switch` statement block instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to just have a window pop up to display the number, you could use something like `showMessageDialog` with an if statement -

Code:

```
if (choice == desiredNumber) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,choice);
}
```

You need to import `javax.swing.JOptionPane` for this to work.